# Laravel 4 search - in view, show value submitted in form

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Below is the beginnings of filter form I have built. It works ok but what I'd like to do is retrieve in my view, the values entered for.  So, in this example I'd like to display "you searched by 'the keyword user entered'", and also display this within the keyword text field.  This will be the same principle when I add select lists.

If the user wishes to change filter settings, or paginate through the results, the values are always stored.

My question is how to do this.  I'm quite sure it's possible in laravel but only know how to do this in PHP

FORM

```
<div class="row">  
    {{ Form::open(array('url'=>'events/search',    'class'=>'form-search', 'role'=>'form')) }}
        <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="input-group">
                    {{ Form::text('search', '', array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Search by keyword.'))}}
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                    {{ Form::submit('Search', array('class'=>'btn btn-default'))}}
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
    {{ Form::close() }}
</div>
```

SEARCH CONTROLLER

```
public function postSearch() {

        $search = Input::get('search');

        $events = DB::table('events')
            ->where(function($query) use ($search)
            {
                $query->where('title', 'LIKE',  '%' . $search . '%')
                ->where('date','>=', DB::raw('CURDATE()'));
            })
        ->orderBy('date', 'DESC')
        ->get();

        $this->layout->content = View::make('events.results', 
            array(
                'events' => $events
                )
            );
    }
```

VIEW

```
@foreach($events as $event)
        <div class="col-md-9">You search for ''</div>
          {{-- filter form will again display here --}}
        <h2>{{ HTML::link("events/$event->id/", "$event->title") }}</h2>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Controller:*

```
public function postSearch() {

    $search = Input::get('search');

    $events = DB::table('events')
        ->where(function($query) use ($search)
        {
            $query->where('title', 'LIKE',  '%' . $search . '%')
            ->where('date','>=', DB::raw('CURDATE()'));
        })
    ->orderBy('date', 'DESC')
    ->get();

    $this->layout->content = View::make('events.results', 
        array(
            'events' => $events,
            'search' => $search <-------- pass the search parameter to view
            )
        );
}
```

*View:*

```
@if(!empty($search))
<div class="col-md-9">You search for {{$search}}</div>   
@endif

@foreach($events as $event)
    {{-- filter form will again display here --}}
    <h2>{{ HTML::link("events/$event->id/", "$event->title") }}</h2>
@endforeach
```

**Two issues:**

- Generally search forms are `GET` and not `POST`. (easier to bookmark, give the links elsewhere)
- put the search term outside the loop.